# Computer will not allow iCloud log in or iCloud account

Tags: icloud, macos

Logging in to any iCloud app gives me an error message:
'Verification failed this action could not be completed. Try again.'
My other 4 computers take my login and password and function normally. Mojave 10.14.2 on all computers.

Comment: "total of 10 devices (with a maximum of 5 computers) associated with your Apple ID."
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7568976